# Interested in OR Interested with

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction

I came across an English question yesterday on a website:

The organisation ___________ to popularise Indian classical music among the youth which has lost ___________ with its cultural roots.

- **A** endeavours, touch
- **B** wishes, interest
- **C** efforts, experience
- **D** exerts, intrigue

The provided answer was B (on a few other websites also) while I chose A and there was no explanation provided. Can somebody please help me out here as I am more convinced that A is better suited here and also I checked if the word *interested* can take the preposition *with* but could not find that also. Thank you.

Comment: "A" would be a perfectly good sentence here. I reckon this is a typo in the answer key. Agree that "interest with" doesn't sound fluent, but you do see some examples online of people saying that informally.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that answer B cannot be correct.

The mistake seems to be with the interest with. It would be written **Interest in**

I've always had an interest **in** astronomy.
He never seems to show any interest **in** his children.
She takes more of an interest **in** politics these days
He has demonstrated a genuine interest **in** the project.
They take a lively interest **in** their grandchildren.
I can honestly say that I have no interest whatsoever **in** the royal family.
an interest **in** chess

Examples CED [INTEREST](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interest)